# Combine two position estimates with different accuracies

Tags: combinations, variance, estimation

Hi smart people of StackExchange!

I have a question regarding the combination of two position estimates (X and Y coordinates) where each position estimate has a different certainty/accuracy.

**Example**

I want to combine the following two position estimates into one position estimate:

```
X1 = 53m +- 96m // Y1 = 28m +- 96m

X2 = 58m +- 50m // Y2 = 23m +- 50m
```

Note that the accuracies (the values after the +- sign) can change per position estimate measurement I take, so a formula that merges these two position estimates should be able to handle varying accuracies.

How can I combine these two position estimates? And is it also possible to determine the accuracy (+- value) of the combined position estimate?

I've looked around and found weighted averages/means, but I don't understand how to apply that method here (if it applies at all).

Hopefully you guys and gals can help me with this one ;)

If you need clarification on the question, please let me know.

**Edit for clarification**

I have a robot of which I want to determine its position. There are two algorithms that are capable of calculating the robot's position, but they have different accuracies.

The first algorithm determines the position of the robot is:
X1 = 53 meter +- 96 meters --> this is the estimate X-coordinate with the accuracy of the algorithm
Y1 = 58 meter +- 50 meters --> this is the estimate Y-coordinate with the accuracy of the algorithm

Now the second algorithm determines a different position (X2 and Y2), but it has a different accuracy (i.e., a different range that the true X and Y coordinates can lie in).

How can I combine the two position estimates to determine the most likely true X and Y coordinate, taking into account the different accuracies.

**Edit 2:** I've removed the word "average" as this is not necessarily what I want. Thanks for the comment :)

Comment: x1  can be as large as 53+ 96= 149 m and x2  can be as large as 58+ 50= 108 m so x1+ x2 can be as large as 149+ 108= 257 m.

Comment: What's the exact meaning of your $\pm$ estimates? If it means the true value is guaranteed to lie in the given rectangular region, then you can combine estimates by taking the intersection of the regions.

Comment: i.e. if Alice tells you that $5<x<10$ and Bob tells you that $8<x<12$, then (unless one of them is wrong) you can conclude that $8<x<10$.

Comment: @GeorgeIvey 

I don't understand how your calculation makes sense for this question, but maybe that's my fault in the question formulation.

@Karl

The +- estimate means that the estimated position (X and Y coordinate) lie within those values. So for the first measurement (X1 and Y1) I am 100% sure that the true value of X lies within X`1 +- 96 meters).

If I understand your second comment correctly, you take the highest lower bound and the lowest upper bound for the range in which the true value lies?

Comment: Another way of looking at it: $x_1= 53\pm 96$ and $x_2= 59\pm 50$. 53+59= 111 and 96+ 50= 146 so $x_1+ x_2= 111\pm 146$.

Comment: @GeorgeIvey  

Your intersection calculation looks promising, but this does not take into account the accuracies in the sense that one position estimate is more accurate than the other, correct? If so, how can this be applied? I'd assume there would have to be some weights applied to both estimates, to ensure that the more accurate estimate (smaller +- value) is taken into consideration more for the final position estimate.

Comment: If you think of each estimate as giving you an upper and lower bound for each coordinate, then to combine the information you should just take the highest lower bound and the lowest upper bound for each coordinate (see my earlier comments).